# Invisible posts

Tags: support, user-interface, meta

The post, [Freedom of speech in scientific discussions - An invitation to more tolerance in Scientific debates](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2342/freedom-of-speech-in-scientific-discussions-an-invitation-to-more-tolerance-in), is currently invisible on the meta front page. I take it this is due to the large negative vote the post has received. Is there some switch I can toggle so that I get to see all active posts, whether they have large negative scores or not?

This may be related to an earlier meta post, "Disappearing post to meta".

[EDIT: No, it's not related to that earlier question, [Disappearing post to meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/284/disappearing-post-to-meta), which was a deleted post --- this one is not deleted, just unpopular]

Comment: When I want to see recent heavily downvoted questions, I click on the Questions button at the top of the page (to the right of the MathOverflow Meta icon).  Right now the post in question appears in the "recent" tab as well as the "active" tab.

Comment: I think this should be toggled off by default on meta.  Meta frequently goes days with no activity, so it's not like bad questions will clutter the front page.  And just as we should be very cautious about closing meta questions, we should be very cautious about hiding them from the view of people who might be able to provide useful feedback.  In addition, people will often downvote things like feature requests to indicate disagreement, but just because a lot of people don't like an idea as stated doesn't mean there is nothing to be gained by discussing and possibly improving it.

Comment: @EricWofsey the threshold is significantly higher on meta (8 vs 4), while the traffic (and thus number of potential voters is lower). This is sufficient in my opinion. The hiding is often quite beneficial, especially for the poster, as it helps to control "piling on" a bit. Finally, as you know it is really not hard to get access to those questions; it is just that they do not jump at you right away. On feature-requests specifically: the etiquette here is to *first create a discussion,* and to post  a f-r only afterwards if there is some support. When followed,  there should be little issue.

Comment: @quid: Ah, I didn't know the threshold was that high on meta.  I still feel like there isn't much point in hiding on meta, but with such a high threshold I can agree it is at least mostly harmless.

Comment: There was a recent question on meta about this: [Why is my feature-request not showing on meta?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4821)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to make posts with very negative scores show up on your front page, but you can see a list of questions sorted like the front page but with no posts hidden at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions?sort=active (which can be reached by clicking the "Questions" button at the top of the page).

Comment: Excellent. Just what I needed to know. Thanks also to @Joel Reyes Noche.