# Why is my feature-request not showing on meta?

Tags: support, bug, meta, questions

I posted my feature request ([Feature request: a possibility to leave mathoverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4818/70594)) yesterday, yet it is not showing on the list of most recent questions.

[image]

I thought it might be the negative votes but on the screenshot above, I see there are questions with negative votes quite visible.

Comment: Here is a similar older post: [Invisible posts](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2346).

Comment: I had an idea for a workaround: You could ask people to vote on an answer rather than the question itself.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't show on the homepage, but you can find it via the [list of questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions?tab=Newest). This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); questions with a score of -4 or lower on the main site and -8 or lower on the meta site are hidden from the homepage.

Reference: [Meta sites' front pages should not hide questions with very low scores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62729/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: Thanks. This is a strange policy for the "feature-request", which offten eventually het dozens of both negative and positive votes.

Comment: Yes, there are various proposals on Meta Stack Exchange to change this in certain circumstances. It looks like the company thinks the -8 vs. -4 distinction is already enough.